# PHP- Send Mail after some Validation

Tags: php

I am new to PHP not an expert by any means. Anyhow, I am building a PHP and HTML contact form and I am getting mixed up on the way to validate field input (trim, strip, htmlspecchars..). Anyways, here is my code, please go easy on me, I am a noob at this.

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$name = $email = $web = $telephone = $pages = $completion_date = $update_option = $hosting_option = $domain_option = $text = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    $web = test_input($_POST["web"]);
    $telephone = test_input($_POST["telephone"]);
    $pages = test_input($_POST["pages"]);
    $completion_date = test_input($_POST["completion_date"]);
    $update_option = test_input($_POST["update_option"]);
    $hosting_option = test_input($_POST["hosting_option"]);
    $domain_option = test_input($_POST["domain_option"]);
    $text = test_input($_POST["text"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

$msg = $name . "\n";
$msg = $email . "\n";
$msg = $web . "\n";
$msg = $telephone . "\n";
$msg = $pages . "\n";
$msg = $completion_date . "\n";
$msg = $update_option . "\n";
$msg = $hosting_option . "\n";
$msg = $domain_option . "\n";
$msg = $text . "\n";

$recipient = "myemail@mydomain.com";
$subject = "Contact Has Been Made..";
$mailheaders = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$mailheaders = "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$mailheaders = "From: <myemail@mydomain.com>, Reply-To: <myemail@mydomain.com>" . "\r\n";
$mailheaders = "Cc: <$email>" . "\r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);
?>
```

Comment: You need to concatenate your `$mailheaders` like so `$mailheaders .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";` and add the `dot` before the `=` for the rest, but don't put a dot for the first `$mailheaders = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";` as well as for `$msg` and `$data`. Any variable which is repeated, needs a dot to concatenate it/them.

Comment: There is a section on SE/SO made especially for "code reviews". Visit http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/ for future use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stripslashes` and `htmlspecialchars` are unnecessary in this context. After all, you are not outputting any HTML that contain the POSTed values.

The problem with your form validation is that I could write anything in the email field, for example, and it would still validate. You should make a case-by-case validation for all the fields so, for example with the email field

```
if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // The email is valid
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}
```

And so on. If you don't *need* them to be what they say the are, you can omit this. Other than that it looks okay.

Comment: Should I use FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS for like, text fields, etc, and of course FILTER_SANITIZE_URL for the URL Field?

Comment: @penweb Yes, it's better than using your own validations. This only matters if you need your data to be valid. If it's going to be read by a person than can just disregard spam/malicious input you can omit it.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue at hand. It's obvious there's a concatenate problem which is not addressed in your answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- But madeddie already addressed it. OP wasn't talking about any particular problem, just a code revision in general.

Comment: @fedeetz You have a point there. However code review should not be posted in this section. The OP should have been informed of that and posted it in SO's code review section.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're probably right. I don't have enough rights to move the question somewhere else or anything like that, though.

Comment: I will be sure to use the codereview site instead for questions that probably will lead to a discussion, thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

It looks okay until the definition of $msg, you keep overwriting it.

Prepend the equals (=) signs after the first with a dot (.)

```
$msg = $name . "\n";
$msg .= $email . "\n";
$msg .= $web . "\n";
... etc
```

Comment: Should I do that with the $mailheaders variable as well?

Comment: Yes, if you're using the PHP standard mail() function. The headers parameter is one string, just like the message body parameter. I just noticed though that that each line in both the headers as well as the message need to be separated by \r\n, not just \n.